# Wordpress Multilinigual

Tags: multi-language

I've got a wordpress website up and running, so lately I've tried making it multilinigual using all the avaibale plugins such as polylang, wp multilinigual, etc... 
So far all the main contents can be easily translated expect the ones that are predefined in the theme, like let's say my [website](http://aplic.cakecreative.net) is about conferences, and there are registration forms prebuilt by the theme. I've got difficulties translating these strings as it doesn't support plugin integration through GUI, can any one please suggest me a better way to handle the corresponding issue ?

Comment: make your theme multilingual or change to one which already supports it.

Comment: Your theme is not supporting the language translations.  So you have to create. MO  And. PO  files for your theme.  And also you have to convert the translatable words into the function like this.  `_("Here your existing theme strings")`.  And when you change language it will apply  the theme too.

Comment: ok great, any useful article I ca study on how to implement?

Comment: If you use a WP Multisite, then can you use your plugins in single mode, that often load there language files. Not all multilingual solutions have a load for this files and this create a lot of problems. If you will also benefits for posts and his translations in the multisite, try the plugin [MultilingualPress](https://wordpress.org/plugins/multilingual-press/)

Comment: Neophyte Polyhistor ,2 useful article:

 - http://www.wpbeginner.com/beginners-guide/how-to-easily-create-a-multilingual-wordpress-site/

 - https://codex.wordpress.org/Multilingual_WordPress

Comment: Transposh (http://transposh.org) can do the translations for both the content and the themes, but it does require the content to be the same.

Note - I am the plugin author, so I am biased